# How do you get a Node.js Buffer from a blob returned by the Node.js 18 fetch implementation (undici-based)?

Tags: node.js, blob, buffer, fetch-api, binaryfiles

How do you get a [Node.js Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) from a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) returned by the Node.js 18 [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) implementation?

I know I can get binary data in the form of a Blob using the Fetch API

```js
const blob = await fetch("https://example.com/image.png")
    .then(r => r.blob())
```

but most libraries expect a Buffer. How do I get a buffer from fetch / convert a blob to a buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `fetch()` to get a blob, you can get an arrayBuffer and then you can do `Buffer.from(arrayBuffer)` to convert it to a nodejs Buffer object.  See [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#static-method-bufferfromarraybuffer-byteoffset-length).

```
const response = await fetch("https://example.com/image.png");
const arrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to convert response from fetch to Buffer using arrayBuffer and Buffer.from

```
function test() {
    fetch("https://example.com/image.png").then(async response =>{
        const buffer = Buffer.from(await response.arrayBuffer());
    });
}
```